# Calculate D(f o g)(1,2)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm doing this problem:

Let: $g:\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a differentiable function such that:

$g(0,0)=(1, 2); \ \ g(1,2)=(3,5); \ \ f(0,0)=(3,5); \ \ f(4,1)=(1,2)$

$Dg(0,0) = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
-1 & 4
\end{array}} \right]; \ \ \ Dg(1,2)= \left[{\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 3 \\
5 & 7
\end{array}}\right]; \ \ \ Df(3, 5) = \left[{\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
3 & 5
\end{array}}\right]; \ \ \ Df = \left[{\begin{array}{cc}
-1  & 2 \\
1 & 3
\end{array}}\right]$

Calculate: $D(f \ o \ g)(1, 2)$

I think the solution is:

$D(f(g))(1,2) = \left[{\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 3 \\
5 & 7
\end{array}}\right]\left[{\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
3 & 5
\end{array}}\right]$

Because I used the chain rule, then: $Dg*Df$, but I'm not sure about that, I mistake?

Comment: The chain rule says that $D(f\circ g)(x)= Df(g(x))\circ Dg(x)$.

Comment: I think you got the matrices backwards.